# excel vba: recordset joining and performance

Tags: mysql, arrays, excel, vba, ado

### The Context

I have an app in excel VBA for making read-only queries on a remote database.

Queries are executed from UDF's.  My app passes an array of data from the recordset object to the function and Excel's fast process for writing an array to a cell range is invoked.

### The Challenge

The app must be able to optionally return field names at the top of the dataset.  This is presenting a huge performance challenge for me.  The only way I know of to append or prepend to a 2D array in VBA is to loop through the entire array.  Normally, I'm spared such a loop by passing the `recordset.getRows()` object directly to my UDF.  However, when combining the list of fields and the result of the query with the looping method (the only method I'm aware of) I double or triple my calculation time for sizable queries.

I benchmarked this: for a query of 2k rows and 5 fields, average calc time without field names included is **4.3 seconds**, vs. **9.8 seconds** with field names

My first try was to combine the field names and recordset on the server using a `UNION` clause in my select statement (my server is MySQL).  This does not work, however, since UNION forces data-type equality, implicitly converting my numerical data to strings.  To convert them back I'd have to loop through the array, negating any efficiency gained.

### My Question

**Is there any object method of the recordset object or of VBA arrays that could be called upon to prepend a row to a large array without looping through the entire large array?**  The field names are all known before the MySQL query is executed.

My loop for joining the arrays is below.  Define a new array `arr` of length of the recordset + 1, then loop through it, first adding the fields, then each row of the recordset array:

```
For r = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
            If r = LBound(arr, 1) Then
                arr(r) = fieldArray
            Else                    
                arr(r) = Application.Index(rs_array, r - 1, 0)
            End If           
Next
```

Comment: In your "join" code it looks like you're going from a 2-D array to a 1-D array (an array of arrays).  Is that intentional?

Comment: Is the purpose of the field names so as to reproduce them at the top of the limited data set on the Excel sheet?  If so, perhaps just use a second array to hold them.  eg:  `V = Range(row_of_field_names)` would produce an array of size `V(1 to 1, 1 to num_of_field_names)` .  This should be faster than looping through the entire array.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld - that was my first thought, but the OP is using UDF's to pass the results back to the worksheet, so only a single array can be returned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `Application.Index` is possibly the slowest way to combine your arrays: use a regular nested loop instead and you won't even notice any hit -

```
Sub TT()

    Dim a(1 To 2000, 1 To 10)

    Dim b(1 To 2000, 1 To 10)
    Dim cc(1 To 2000)

    Dim r, c, t

    t = Timer
    For r = 1 To 2000
        For c = 1 To 10
            b(r, c) = a(r, c)
        Next c
    Next r
    Debug.Print "Loop", Timer - t '>> 0.015625 sec

    t = Timer
    For r = 1 To 2000
        cc(r) = Application.Index(a, r, 0)
    Next r
    Debug.Print "Index", Timer - t '>> 4.195313 sec

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks!  I had some intuitions about the cost of loops vs `application.index()` which were wildly inaccurate.  This method reduces the additional overhead to a tenth of a second.